# Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS image on a flash drive isn't seen by the booter. 22.04 works fine and Ubuntu can be installed

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, system-installation, windows-10

I am a new ubuntu user and have a rough time with installation.

I need to install Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS to be compatible with ROS Neotic.

I am a Windows 10 User. A couple of days ago I installed 22.04 and it worked correctly, but I needed to downgrade so I deleted it by emptying the partition. Then I burned the 20.04.5 image on a flash drive. Next, I booted it in the boot menu and it boots windows instead. Other distributions such as Ubuntu Budgie 22.04.1 also booted correctly.

Images burned by Rufus. I tried both partitionings: MBR and GPT.

I will be grateful for any advice on how to solve this problem :)

Comment: You set the BIOS in the computer to boot from USB? You verified the image before burning it? https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview You checked to make sure the computer was running legacy and not EFI based on how you set up the USB?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it. The problem was with Windows Secure Boot. When I disabled it, everything worked fine.
Still help for your time :)